# Changing the angle depending on position changes

Tags: scripting

I'm writing a scenario to a game which allows to use custom scripts.
I want to change the camera angle using SetCameraHeading(float in_fAngle), where:
"0 is facing east, 90 is facing north, 180 is facing west, and 270 is facing south".
I made something like this:

```
//The map size is 150x300:
NWX = 0;
NWY = 300;
NEX = 150;
NEY = 300;
SWX = 0;
SWY = 0;
SEX = 150;
SEY = 0;

Player1NW = GetDistanceFromUnitToPoint("Survivor1", NWX, NWY);
Player1NE = GetDistanceFromUnitToPoint("Survivor1", NEX, NEY);
Player1SW = GetDistanceFromUnitToPoint("Survivor1", SWX, SWY);
Player1SE = GetDistanceFromUnitToPoint("Survivor1", SEX, SEY);

Player1NWDiff = Player1NWOld - Player1NW;
Player1NEDiff = Player1NEOld - Player1NE;
Player1SWDiff = Player1SWOld - Player1SW;
Player1SEDiff = Player1SEOld - Player1SE;
//Need to set camera heading here:
SetCameraHeading(Player1CurrentAngle, false);

Player1NWOld = Player1NW;
Player1NEOld = Player1NE;
Player1SWOld = Player1SW;
Player1SEOld = Player1SE;
```

The problem is I don't know how to change the angle depending on position changes (for example, when an unit is walking it changes to: Player1NWDiff = -0.02, Player1NEDiff = -0.02, Player1SWDiff = 0.04, Player1SEDiff = 0.03 etc.)

Does anybody know how should I calculate it to get a correct angle (0 to 360)?